# Lift Sails inside Docker container

Tags: docker, sails.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I know there are multiple examples (actually only a few) out there, and I've looked into some and tried to apply them to my case but then when I try to lift the container (`docker-compose up`) I end up with more or less the same error every time.

My folder structure is:

```
sails-project
--app
----api
----config
----node_modules
----.sailsrc
----app.js
----package.json

--docker-compose.yml
--Dockerfile
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
sails:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8001:80"
  links:
    - postgres
  volumes:
    - ./app:/app
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=development
  command: node app

postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "8002:5432"
```

And the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:0.12.3

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

# the dependencies are already installed in the local copy of the project, so 
# they will be copied to the container
ADD app /app

CMD ["/app/app.js", "--no-daemon"]

RUN cd /app; npm i
```

I tried also having `RUN npm i -g sails` instead (in the `Dockerfile`) and `command:sails lift`, but I'm getting:

[image]

Naturally, I tried different configurations of the `Dockerfile` and then with different commands (`node app`, `sails lift`, `npm start`, etc...), but constantly ending up with the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `command: node app` you are overriding the [**command**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/command) `CMD ["/app/app.js", "--no-daemon"]` which as a consequence will have no effect. `WORKDIR /app` [will create an app folder](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir) so you don't have to `RUN mkdir /app`. And most important you have to `RUN cd /app; npm i` before `CMD ["/app/app.js", "--no-daemon"]`. NPM dependencies have to be installed before you start your app.

Comment: Forgot to say that I've got the dependencies installed in my local copy of the project, so `ADD app /app` will copy the dependencies. I will update the OP now with this info. :)

Comment: @Milkncookiez sure. However in a vanilla sails project the sails folder in node_modules is a symlink. In your dockerfile just the symlink will be copied and not the entire folder. To test this install sails locally in your project folder.

Comment: I did, and it is running alright now, I don't know why and how. I didn't really change much in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @Milkncookiez glad I could help :D